# Is there a way to effectively update CAN data in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Currently I am receiving CAN data in real time using socketcan API in `main.cpp` file.

I am constantly updating the data frame of CAN in one variable in `main.cpp`.

I want to express the gauge in real time by passing the variable containing the CAN data frame in `main.cpp` to the QML animation gauge.

I need to detect the change of the variable containing CAN data in QML in real time. I wonder if there is an effective way.

I tried to share data with QML using `emit`.
However, the function written by `emit` inside `device-> connect (device, & QCanBusDevice :: framesReceived, [device] () {...}` does not work.

When using it, I get the error

> '`this`' cannot be implicitly captured in this context.

I looked up the error, but did not find the answer.

```
if (QCanBus::instance()->plugins().contains(QStringLiteral("socketcan"))) {
            qWarning() << "plugin available";
        }

        QString errorString;
        QCanBusDevice *device = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(
            QStringLiteral("socketcan"), QStringLiteral("vcan0"), &errorString);
        if (!device) {
            qWarning() << errorString;
        } else {
            device->connectDevice();
            std::cout << "connected vcan0" << std::endl;

            device->connect(device, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, [device]() {

            QCanBusFrame frame = device->readFrame();
            QString testV = frame.toString();

            QString qvSpeed = frame.payload();

            std::string text = testV.toUtf8().constData();
            std::string vSpeed = qvSpeed.toUtf8().constData();

            //At that point the vVal values ​​are being updated in real time.
            //I want to pass the updated vVal to qml gui in real time.
            int vVal = static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[0]);
            //emit sendMessage(vVal); // 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context error.

            std::cout << text << std::endl;
            });
        }
```

As of now, `main.cpp` can't send the data and QML can't solve the error.

Inside `device-> connect`, `emit sendMessage (vVal);` will cause "'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context" error.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to implement animation by expressing QML GUI data in real time.

Comment: to fix that error you need to change the capture: `[device]` should become `[this, device]` or even all capturing: `[=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capture clause only captures `device`.  You need to also explicitly capture `this`:

```
device->connect(device, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, [this,device]{ /*...*/ });
```

BTW, note that there's no need to specify the `()` for a no-args lambda expression.